# fixed position is not working in android browser

Tags: android

Right now fixed position is not working in my mobile android browse can any help on this issue [see my link](http://www.creativecorp.in/tcg/index.html)

Please give good solution for online mobile testing for different devices present i am using Ripple in Chrome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In wich version of Android's browser are you trying to fix the position? Not in every version  is supported the fixed position. You can have a look [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed).

Comment: I checked in both versions 4 & 2.2 not working any thing but rest of browsers it's working

Comment: I was checking your site, it seems you're making tests on it because the code is changing.
Normally this should work: position:fixed. If you have any other styles, like position:absolute or something like that you could have troubles.